# Javascript - hiding table rows is very slow

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

newbie question here:

I have a huge HTML table, 30 000 rows lets say, each row has an class name (there are cca 10 in total). I need a JS function, that filter (show/hide) all rows with a specific class.

Showing them (removing an attribute) is relatively fast, but hiding them (setting attribute) takes really long.

This is how the table looks like:

```
<tr class="a" show="off">...</tr>
<tr class="b" show="off">...</tr>
<tr class="c" show="off">...</tr>
<tr class="a" show="off">...</tr>
<tr class="b" show="off">...</tr>
<tr class="c" show="off">...</tr>
```

there is an CSS rule

```
tr[show="off"] {
    display:none;
}
```

and my JS code to show them would be removing that show attribute

```
function showTr (c){
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName(c)
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        rows[i].removeAttribute("show")
    }
}
```

and code to hide them

```
function hideTr (c){
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName(c)
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        rows[i].setAttribute("show","off")
    }
}
```

I apologize if there is an topic covering this, I have not found anything. And thank you for any advice.

Comment: maybe instead of setting an atribute you could change the css with javascript

Comment: 30k rows is the issue, you make dom sad :(, use pagination instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mutating each DOM node, you could build a css and inject it into `<head>` and let the browser handle the rest.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('[data-toggle]');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleRows);

function toggleRows() {
    const STYLE_ID = 'table-row-hide';
    const prevStyle = document.getElementById(STYLE_ID);
    if (prevStyle) {
        prevStyle.parentNode.removeChild(prevStyle);
    } else {
        const css = `
            .hideable {
                display: none;
            }
        `;
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.id = STYLE_ID;
        style.innerHTML = css;

        document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
}
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button data-toggle>Toggle</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideable">
        <td>c</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideable">
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```